# How to delete all rows in database on one click

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I have a two database table, on a single button click in my program , I want to delete all the two table's data. But there's always one datum left on the table.. Here is my code:

```
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to delete the log? ", "Log", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );
                    if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){ 
                        try{

                            Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RIM");
                            Statement st1 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                            Statement st2 = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                            String sql1 = "select * from userLogIn";
                            ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(sql1);
                            String sql2 = "select * from userViewed";
                            ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery(sql2);

                            while(rs1.next()){          
                                rs1.deleteRow();
                                rs1.first();
                            }

                            while(rs2.next()){                                  
                                rs2.deleteRow();
                                rs2.first();
                            }

                            editorPane.setText("");
                        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is only one element left, your call to `first()` sets the cursor to that element, but then the `next()` call in the while condition will return false, causing the exit from the loop and thus the `deleteRow` won't be executed.

Use [`rs.beforeFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst%28%29)`.

Note that your code has lots of issues, so get this answers as "for educational purposes" only.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you iterating over a `select` record set at all? It's incredibly inefficient.

If you want to delete all data from those tables, you can simply execute the statements:

```
delete from userLogin;
delete from userViewed;
```

(or use `truncate`).